# Python script containing connection to psycopg2 exits without error on Windows Command Prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, command-line

When I try to run a python script on windows command prompt using

```
"C:\path_to_conda_env\anaconda3\envs\virutal_env\python.exe" "C:\path_to_script\script.py"
```

the script executes until it hits a connection I'm making to using `psycopg2` and then exits without any messages. However, running the same command above on Anaconda prompt works with no issues. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some potential cases

- environment variables: anaconda prompt might set some environment variables that are essential for some of the packages to run correctly.
  You can activate the conda environemnt in the Windows command prompt.

  ```
  "C:\path_to_conda_env\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" virtual_env
   python "C:\path_to_script\script.py"
  ```
- missing dependencies: the conda environemnt hay have dependecies installed that aren't available when you run the script outside of the Anaconda prompt. Make sure all required dependencies, and any of its system dependencies, are correctly installed from the Windows command prompt.